# CSS Border-Radius, but pixelated

Tags: html, css

I want to create a rounded border in CSS that looks pixelated when zoomed in.

This is what a rounded border looks like up close: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9Q2g.jpg

And this is what I'm trying to make it look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B93wm.jpg

This is a specific aesthetic that I'm trying to achieve with my site, but I could not find any tutorials on how to do this. What I want to know is if this is possible outside of going oldschool and using images. I'm sure anyone who wants to recreate old-fashioned looking webpages will find this useful, and there's an entire community of pixel-artists that would love to use this too.

The fact that I can find no help on this tells me it's either not possible or I'm literally the only person who cares about this. If it's the latter then that's a serious negligence on the part of this programming language, especially when this option is already available for images with image-rendering.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what advantage does that offer you?

Comment: You might be able to achieve something with [`border-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image), but I guess that won't be easy to make something modular...

Comment: i dont think this is possible without background image or playing with gradient

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of doing this sort of thing, each with their own tradeoffs.

---

1. Clip paths: You can use clip paths to hide part of an element. It keeps the element's current width by clipping part of the element's content.

   [This pixelated corners generator](https://pixelcorners.lukeb.co.uk/) uses that approach. You could also use CSS variables to allow for different results without having to use the generator each time.

   An example output:

   ```css
   .pixel-corners {
        clip-path: polygon(
          0px 8px,
          4px 8px,
          4px 4px,
          8px 4px,
          8px 0px,
          calc(100% - 8px) 0px,
          calc(100% - 8px) 4px,
          calc(100% - 4px) 4px,
          calc(100% - 4px) 8px,
          100% 8px,
          100% calc(100% - 8px),
          calc(100% - 4px) calc(100% - 8px),
          calc(100% - 4px) calc(100% - 4px),
          calc(100% - 8px) calc(100% - 4px),
          calc(100% - 8px) 100%,
          8px 100%,
          8px calc(100% - 4px),
          4px calc(100% - 4px),
          4px calc(100% - 8px),
          0px calc(100% - 8px)
        );
      }
   ```

   ```html
   <img src="https://pixelcorners.lukeb.co.uk/spaceship.png" class="pixel-corners" />
   ```

---

2. Box shadows: Especially if you have a solid background, you can fake a border radius with `box-shadow`s. Note that it *adds* to the element's current width, so you might want to compensate for that in your layout or width setting. For example:

   ```css
   button {
     all: unset; /* Demo style */
     
     box-shadow:
       -4px 0 0 -2px black,   /* Left inner shadow */
       -8px 0 0 -4px black, /* Leftmost shadow */
        4px 0 0 -2px black,   /* Right inner shadow */
        8px 0 0 -4px black; /* Rightmost shadow */
   }
   button.debug {
     box-shadow:
       -4px 0 0 -2px red,   /* Left inner shadow */
       -8px 0 0 -4px green, /* Leftmost shadow */
        4px 0 0 -2px red,   /* Right inner shadow */
        8px 0 0 -4px green; /* Rightmost shadow */
   }


   /* Demo styles */
   button {
     cursor: pointer;
     background-color: black;
     color: white;
     font-family: sans-serif;
     padding: 4px 4px;
   }
   div {
     margin: 4px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div>
     <button>Test</button>
   </div>
   <div>
     <button class="debug">Test</button>
   </div>
   ```

---

3. Border images: In general you shouldn't need to use this approach these days but could be good if you have a more complicated border.

---

4. Pseudo-elements: Again, you shouldn't need to use this approach most the time but can be good if you need specific effects.